# exclude an entire word and force a lazy regex behaviour

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I would like to have a regexp that matches all groups of words in a text that start from "a" and end in "e" with the exception of those that end in the "the" article. E.g., in the sentence "And here are the four sleeping guards, smitten from the side by an invincible flood of sunlight" I need to match "an invincible", but not "are the" (my other question is how to force vba match "are" instead of the superfluous "are the" in the first place). So far, I've come up with the following pattern: \ba([^.,?;!]){1,50}[^h]e\b (I also exclude certain punctuation marks and limit the string length to about 50 characters at most: the latter is the only way I'm currently able to suppress reduntantly long, greedy that is, matches). My very imperfect solution helps me to do away with the word groups ending in "the" but obviously with those ending in "he" as well, which I don't want (I've played with lookahead, but unfortunately been unable to apply the concept in my case). Also, I'm not happy with such an inefficient way to arrive at suppressing overly long matches. Could you please help me.

Comment: Would "at the lake" be a whole match?

Comment: Yes, it would. Just like "already seen the cycle" in "We have already seen the cycle open, on the facing lunette". Aaron's otherwise very helpful answer below seems to exclude such matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, the is the regex you need

```
\ba[\w ]+?(?<!\bth)e\b
```

- `[\w ]` matches all word characters and spaces. Change this if you want to match phrases with commas and periods as well.
- `+?` is a lazy quantifier. This means that it will only keep matching if the string in front does not match the next sub pattern.
- `(?<!\bth)` is a negative lookbehind to ensure there is no `th` before the `e`.

Comment: Thank you. However, as far as I understand, MS Word VBA is deprived of the lookbehind functionality, so this pattern yields no matches.

Comment: @Svetlana I see. Then you can replace the lookbehind with `(\Bth|[^t]h|[^h])`, which Aaron has suggested. Full regex: `\ba[\w ]+?(\Bth|[^t]h|[^h])e\b`

Comment: yes, now it works perfect! thank you and Aaron very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a negative lookbehind :

```
\ba[^.,?;!]{1,50}(?<!th)e\b
```

If that's not possible, your approach needs to be extended to handling the 3 letters of the word : the letter before the final `e` can be `h` if the one before isn't `t` :

```
\ba[^.,?;!]{1,50}([^t]h|[^h])e\b
```

Also I guess it can be "the" if it's part of a word such as "lathe" ? In this case, this should work :

```
\ba[^.,?;!]{1,50}(\Bth|[^t]h|[^h])e\b
```

Comment: Thank you, Aaron. Unfortunately, lookbehind is unavailable in the VBScript RegExp flavor. I've tried your other suggestions. The last one (\ba[^.,?;!]{1,50}(\Bth|[^t]h|[^h])e+\b -- with the plus sign)  works but excludes the word groups that have "the" inside them (but not ending in "the") as I've noted above in my response to Sweeper.